# Switching left and right mouse button functions without switching mousepad buttons

Tags: mouse, orientation, mouse-buttons

I'm left handed and thus I've switched the functions of the left and right mouse buttons so that the right button is the primary. However, I find that when I'm not using the mouse and thus need to use the trackpad and its buttons, I don't want them to be flipped. I want the primary to remain on the left. Is there a way to have a discordance between an external mouse and the built-in track pad?

Comment: Some mouse software allow you to remap the buttons, but I don't know of a way to do this without third party software in Windows.

Comment: The system itself usualy allows for the trading up of the buttons, for left handed use. The problem Great Kindness is presented with is, it is system wide. Many of the 3rd party tools are also system wide, hooking into the same system. This function might want to be accomplished for the hardware more at the driver level. But What OS is it to begin with? First thing to check for would be software that communicates with the driver for the touchpad, like if it was synaptics , various versions of its software had the ability to map either the buttons, or places on the pad.

Answer (score 0):

In both Windows 7 and Windows 10, the Button tab of the Mouse Properties control panel (Run > main.cpl) shows me a Devices pop-up under Button configuration. That lets me specify whether I'm making settings for either "Synaptics TouchPad V7.5 on PS/2 Port" or "Other Pointing Devices". In particular I can make the Synaptics settings right-handed and the other settings left-handed, or vice versa. I hope that works for you, too. If not, please provide specifics about how your system differs from mine.